# Can people change their name to my previous name?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

If I change my name, what happens to my old name?

Can people change their name to my previous Minecraft name?

Answer (score 15):

> If you change your username, your old name is held for 37 days. This gives you an extra week to change back if you've made a mistake or changed your mind.

[Source](https://help.mojang.com/customer/en/portal/articles/928638-minecraft-usernames)